# Javascript: validate grid contents

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a grid whose cells may be coloured either black or white, write a function to validate that these conditions are met:

1. Rows have an equal amount of black and white cells
2. Columns also have an equal amount of black and white cells

Input looks like:

```
[
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "W", "B"],
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "W", "B"]
]
```

This input validates because it has the same amount of black and white spaces, both vertically and horizontally.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
const boardgame = [
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "W", "B"],
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "W", "B"]
];

const numOfH = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < boardgame.length; i++) {
  if (boardgame[i] === 'H') {
    numOfH++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask] and [help] and [tour]  Maybe post the code you have attempted and explain what is wrong with it.  thanks

Comment: I'll vote to reopen as soon as @youngprogrammer provides their own attempt at solving this.

Comment: @Gershom const boardgame = [
["B", "W", "B", "W"],

 ["W", "B", "W", "B"],

 ["B", "W", "B", "W"],

 ["W", "B", "W", "B"]
];

const numOfH = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < boardgame.length; i++) {
  if (boardgame[i] === 'H') {
    numOfH++;
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

Here is the validation function. In it, you need to pass the board as the only parameter, and it will return `true` or `false`, depending on your conditions (stated in the question).

```
const board1 = [ //should be true
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "W", "B"],
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "W", "B"]
];

const board2 = [ // should be false
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "B", "W"],
  ["B", "W", "B", "W"],
  ["W", "B", "W", "B"]
];


function validate_board(boardgame) {
    let obk_rows = {W: 0, B: 0};
    let obk_cols = {};


    var validated_rows = true;
    var validated_cols = true;



    for (var i = 0; i < boardgame.length; i++) {
        //first, rows
        for(var x = 0; x<boardgame[i].length; x++) {
            obk_rows[boardgame[i][x]] += 1;
        }

        if(obk_rows["B"] != obk_rows["W"]) {
            validated_rows = false;
        }

        //now cols:

        let n = 0;
        while (n < boardgame[i].length) {
            var sym = boardgame[i][n];
            if(obk_cols[sym+"-"+n]) {
                obk_cols[sym+"-"+n] += 1;
            } else {
                obk_cols[sym+"-"+n] = 1;
            }

            n++
        }



    }


    for(var i = 0; i<boardgame.length; i++) {
        var currnt = "-"+i;


        if(obk_cols["B"+currnt] != obk_cols["W"+currnt]) {
            validated_cols = false;
        }
        
    }

    //console.log(obk_cols);

    return (validated_rows && validated_cols);
}



console.log(validate_board(board1)); // => true
console.log(validate_board(board2)); // => false
```